# First Available Cell in Column within Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am creating a macro to take an entry and put it on the first available line.  this is what I have so far.  It doesn't work, but what I am trying to do is to use the Range function to select the first available line in the column using the `SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn()` macro.  How am I doing this wrong? THANKS!!

```
Sub SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn()
   Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
'
Sub OUT()
'
' OUT Macro
'
'
    Sheets("Interface").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Items out").Select
    Range("SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn(B)").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Interface").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Items out").Select
    Range("SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn(A)").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn(C)").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Now
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update your `SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn` with parameters (e.g. column letter or number, and sheetname)

also avoid usage of `.select`, so your code can be something like this (this is just an example)

```
Public cl As Range
Sub GetFirstEmptyCellColumn(ShName$, col$)
    Set cl = Sheets(ShName).Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub

Sub OUT()
    With Sheets("Interface")
         GetFirstEmptyCellColumn "Items out", "B": cl.Value = .[B2].Value
         GetFirstEmptyCellColumn "Items out", "A": cl.Value = .[B3].Value
         GetFirstEmptyCellColumn "Items out", "C": cl.Value = Now
         .[B2,B3].ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

or it can be something like this:

```
Sub InsertIntoFirstEmptyCellColumn(shSource$, clSource$, shDest$, col$)
     Sheets(shDest).Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets(shSource).Range(clSource).Value
     Sheets(shSource).Range(clSource).ClearContents
End Sub

Sub OUT()
    InsertIntoFirstEmptyCellColumn "Interface", "B2", "Items out", "B"
    InsertIntoFirstEmptyCellColumn "Interface", "B3", "Items out", "A"
    Sheets("Items out").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now
End Sub
```

but better way (imho) is to replace `Sub SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn()` with a `function`, so your code can looks like this:

```
Function GetFirstEmptyCellColumn(ShName$, col$) As Range
    Set GetFirstEmptyCellColumn = Sheets(ShName).Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Function

Sub OUT()
    With Sheets("Interface")
         GetFirstEmptyCellColumn("Items out", "B").Value = .[B2].Value
         GetFirstEmptyCellColumn("Items out", "A").Value = .[B3].Value
         GetFirstEmptyCellColumn("Items out", "C").Value = Now
         .[B2,B3].ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn(col)
    Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
'
Sub OUT()
'
' OUT Macro
'
'
    Sheets("Interface").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Items out").Select
    SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn "b"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Interface").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Items out").Select
    SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn "a"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    SelectFirstEmptyCellColumn "c"
    ActiveCell.Value = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this worked!! But the "selectFirstEmptyCellColumn(col)" command selected the first cell in only column A, where as it should have selected the first in Column A, then B, then C.  Would you know how to fix this? So it put the two entries in column A, instead of putting it in B and C

Comment: @CollinTodd usage of `.select` method is a bad practice

Comment: @Vasily How else should I select the cell I want and change sheets? Is there a better way? I am fairly new to VBA

Comment: @CollinTodd see my post

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution which avoids the usage of .Select:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Interface")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Items out")
    lRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wsData.Range("B2").Cut wsDest.Cells(lRow, "B")
    wsData.Range("B3").Cut wsDest.Cells(lRow, "A")
    wsDest.Cells(lRow, "C").Value = Now

End Sub
```